# What is the result of initiating members with default! statement in C# .net?

Tags: c#, .net, initialization, default, record

Yes, I tried to google around and found everything possible from null-coalescing operator to `default` keyword, which everything kind of bypasses (as of now) my curiosity about these statements:

```
public record Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; init; } = default!;
    public string LastName { get; init; } = default!;
};
```

The snippet comes from [this MS official site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-9#record-types).

So while I can try out what this code yelds in runtime record instantiation, can anyone please generally explain what is the beauty and magic behind the `default!` statements ?

Thank you.

Comment: You can use search in the site you provided:  [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/default) and then follow the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/default-values)

Comment: @SouXin Thanks for the hint. Yap - I also did search on MS official web/search tool there provided, which let me without answers. Did you try it too with better results ? Eager to hear :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`default`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/default) keyword on it's own says use the default value for this type, in this case a `null` since `string` is a reference type.

The `!` suffix is the [null forgiving operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-forgiving). It suppresses any warnings about a value potentially being null. Without it in this code, you would receive the following warning which is a feature of [nullable reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references):

> CS8625: Cannot convert null literal to non-nullable reference type

Answer (score 2):

There are two things to consider

1. The `default` keyword denotes the value of a type where all the bits are set to `0`. E.g. for an `int` this is `0`, for a `double` it is `0.0` and for a reference type like `string`, this is `null`.
2. In a [Nullable context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references) the two properties are non-nullable, therefore, you are in principle not allowed to assign them `null`. If you know it better than the compiler, you can use the [! (null-forgiving) operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-forgiving) to tell the compiler that `null` is okay in this case.

Why assign `default!`, i.e., `null` to those properties? Declaring a property with an `init` accessor does not ensure that the constructor will be called with an object initializer setting these properties to a non-null value. Even if you know that your code will be doing it. The purpose of this `= default!` property initializer is simply to suppress any compiler warnings about this issue.

C# 11 will introduce a [required modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/required) to force initialization of a property and to suppress this compiler warning.

```cs
public required string FirstName { get; init; }
```

A code using this property will not compile until you either initialize the property in the constructor or in an object initializer.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed and thorough answer.
Very useful info, though it goes a bit beyond the Q. scope - which is not bad.
Its just my excuse why I chose the simpler answer by @DavidG as the ONE - for a quick reference of anyone coming across.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @SouXin, you can use this [official documentation link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/default-values) to check the default value of each C# type.

However, in your case, since `string` is a reference type, `default!` is the same as `null!`. This assignment is used to tell the compiler that the developer is sure that the property is never null, by using `!`, which suppresses the null warning. This is part of the `nullable` feature.

Otherwise, the compiler would return warning, saying that `FistName` and `LastName` can be `null`, and thus, should be of type `string?`.

This is just an intermediate solution, starting with `C# 11`, the recommended solution of telling the compiler that a property won't be null is by using the `required` keyword.

So instead of having:

```cs
public string FirstName { get; init; } = default!;
```

you would use:

```cs
public required string FirstName { get; init; }
```